How to make a barplot with rounded corners in R
I have this dataset:
df <- data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), value = c(10, 20, 15, 30, 25))

I want to create a barplot with rounded corners. Lastly, R had a package called ggchicklet but currently it is deprecated by CRAN.

It doesn't look like ggchicklet was ever on CRAN. You can install it from github. See https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggchicklet

Using plot(., type='h').
> with(df, 
+      plot(value, type='h', lwd=80, xaxt='n', col='blue',
+           xlim=c(.5, nrow(df) + .5), ylim=range(value)*c(1, 1.2), las=1)) +
+   axis(1, axTicks(1), df$category)



One way to fake this using ggplot2 is to use geom_segment(lineend = "round"). It rounds both sides so I put the starting points below the bottom axis to cut them off:
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), value = c(10, 20, 15, 30, 25))

transform(df, start = -10) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = start, yend = value, group = category)) +
  geom_segment(lineend = "round", linewidth = 20) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, NA)) +
  labs(y = "value")


